# jsPDF Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Adding regular png images was no problem with jsPDF, but now i send a generated image from my server and the browser console displays this error when rendering the PDF file:

> Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

obviously the image is not incomplete or corrupt because i can see the response from the server and the image is fine.
Also to avoid render the pdf file before the image is ready i make a check to a that holds the image value variable if is undefined/null.
the format of my image is

> var image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...etc";

What could be the problem?

**Edit:** i changed the format of the image to jpg and this error shows

```
Supplied data is not a JPEG
```

if i use this library `jspdf.plugin.addimage.js` the images are rendered correctly but not the png images.

**edit: 2** i made a solution modifying the `jspdf.plugin.addimage.js` file function `addImage`, i just changed the name of the function and added those generated images to pdf with that function, since the version of `jspdf.min.js` has the same name for the same function with this way it won't override the function i can use the one that works with normal images and the ones generated by the server.

Answer (score 5):

This type of error occurs because the image has not finished loading when you send to jsPdf, use onLoad event to check the image loaded completely. for Example -

```
 /* where src = full image url
        callback = is callback function
        outputFormat = image output format */
    function toDataUrl(src, callback, outputFormat) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function () {

                   /*image completely converted to base64string */
                    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var dataURL;
                    canvas.height = this.height;
                    canvas.width = this.width;
                    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);

                    /* call back function */
                    callback(dataURL);
                };
                img.src = src;
                if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
                    img.src = appConfig.config.dummyImage;
                    img.src = src;
                }
            }



  function callbackBase64(base64Img)
    {
           /*base64Img contains full base64string of image   */
           console.log(base64Img);
    }
```

call above function and get base64string of image -

```
toDataUrl('http://example1.com/image1.jpg', callbackBase64(base64Img), "image/png");
```

Comment: What is `base64Img` supposed to be defined as?

Comment: "base64Img" is just a parameter. The callback/callbackBase64 function is used to just debug the output of the function *toDataUrl*.